# How can I cross out booked dates on full calendar

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to be able to cross out the days from 2023-07-25 to 2023-07-30 I have read the docs but can't seem to make anything work. I tried using events but I can't add any type of classes to the text components there self to give a text-decoration of a line- through. Is there a way to get those elements and apply that style to them. My goal is to make a booking calendar and I will be happy for any suggestions of a different calendar library besides Full Calender that you prefer using.

```js
function showDates(selectedDates) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("dates-selected")[0];

  var text = "From " + selectedDates[0] + " To " + selectedDates[1];

  element.textContent = text;
}

function clearshowDates(selectedDates) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("dates-selected")[0];
  element.textContent = "";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var selectedDates = [];
  var bookedDates = ["2023-07-25", "2023-07-30"];

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",

    events: [{
      start: "2023-07-25",
      end: "2023-07-27",
      display: "background",
    }, ],

    dateClick: function(info) {
      var clickedDate = info.dateStr;
      var todayDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log(todayDate);

      if (clickedDate >= todayDate) {
        if (selectedDates.length === 0) {
          // First click: Select the start date
          selectedDates.push(clickedDate);
        } else if (selectedDates.length === 1) {
          // Second click: Check if the clicked date is different from the start date
          if (clickedDate < selectedDates[0]) {
            selectedDates.unshift(clickedDate); // Insert the clicked date as the new start date
          } else {
            selectedDates.push(clickedDate); // Append the clicked date as the end date
          }

          showDates(selectedDates);

          var currentDate = selectedDates[1];
          var dateObject = new Date(currentDate);
          dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate() + 1);
          var formattedDate = dateObject.toISOString().split("T")[0];
          console.log(formattedDate);

          console.log(selectedDates);
          calendar.addEvent({
            start: selectedDates[0],
            end: formattedDate,
            display: "background",
          });
        } else if (clickedDate >= todayDate) {
          // Third click or same date clicked again: Clear the selected dates and add the new date as a new day
          selectedDates = [clickedDate];
          clearshowDates();

          // Remove previous events
          calendar.getEvents().forEach(function(event) {
            event.remove();
          });

          // Display the new selected date as a background event (new single day)
        }
        calendar.addEvent({
          start: clickedDate,
          display: "background",
        });
      }
    },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dates-selected"></div>
</body>

<script src="cal.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `text-decoration: line-through` to the proper dated element, for example `[data-date="2023-07-19"]`.

Or better yet, prepare a css class `booked` that will hold the styling for a booked date. Then you can add or remove this class to the proper dates using javascript.

```js
function showDates(selectedDates) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("dates-selected")[0];

  var text = "From " + selectedDates[0] + " To " + selectedDates[1];

  element.textContent = text;
}

function clearshowDates(selectedDates) {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("dates-selected")[0];
  element.textContent = "";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var selectedDates = [];
  var bookedDates = ["2023-07-25", "2023-07-30"];

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",

    events: [{
      start: "2023-07-25",
      end: "2023-07-27",
      display: "background",
    }, ],

    dateClick: function(info) {
      var clickedDate = info.dateStr;
      var todayDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log(todayDate);

      if (clickedDate >= todayDate) {
        if (selectedDates.length === 0) {
          // First click: Select the start date
          selectedDates.push(clickedDate);
        } else if (selectedDates.length === 1) {
          // Second click: Check if the clicked date is different from the start date
          if (clickedDate < selectedDates[0]) {
            selectedDates.unshift(clickedDate); // Insert the clicked date as the new start date
          } else {
            selectedDates.push(clickedDate); // Append the clicked date as the end date
          }

          showDates(selectedDates);

          var currentDate = selectedDates[1];
          var dateObject = new Date(currentDate);
          dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate() + 1);
          var formattedDate = dateObject.toISOString().split("T")[0];
          console.log(formattedDate);

          console.log(selectedDates);
          calendar.addEvent({
            start: selectedDates[0],
            end: formattedDate,
            display: "background",
          });
        } else if (clickedDate >= todayDate) {
          // Third click or same date clicked again: Clear the selected dates and add the new date as a new day
          selectedDates = [clickedDate];
          clearshowDates();

          // Remove previous events
          calendar.getEvents().forEach(function(event) {
            event.remove();
          });

          // Display the new selected date as a background event (new single day)
        }
        calendar.addEvent({
          start: clickedDate,
          display: "background",
        });
      }
    },
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
[data-date="2023-07-19"],
[data-date="2023-07-20"],
[data-date="2023-07-21"] {
  background: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="dates-selected"></div>
</body>

<script src="cal.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do inside Full Calendar such as adding a class to the booked dates. Such as full calendar events but adding class name to the events from a certain start to end range https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing such as like this but target the text within it

Comment: are you asking how to implement `showDates(selectedDates)`?

Comment: no I am asking if I have var bookedDates = ["2023-07-25", "2023-07-30"]; and I want to cross out the dates from 07-25 to 07-30 using something inside full calendar in order for those dates to be crossed out

Comment: I don't want to use a css styling as my booked dates can change in the future -Thank you for helping me on this matter

Comment: @JaneSmith just add an event to the calendar to show the times where there is already a booking. There is the option to show it as a [background event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events), if that helps. You can then add a CSS class to any events which represent this information (or to a whole event source if it's simpler) as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing with the `className` property. It's a bit unclear what problem you are having, exactly.

Comment: @JaneSmith `I don't want to use a css styling as my booked dates can change in the future`...that doesn't make any sense. You can can apply CSS to any events, at any time. A CSS rule is just a rule which defines how something looks. Your code can then apply that appearance to any events it needs to, or to none, and you can change it dynamically.